# Mixed performance from monitor headphones plugged into audio interface

Tags: monitoring

Is there any reason why a perfectly good pair of headphones (Sennheiser Momentum) will be seemingly fine when plugged into a 3.5mm jack (for instance, my iPhone), but completely bomb when plugged in to a 1/4" adapter for use with Hi Fi or (more importantly) my Focusrite Saffire monitor output?

When I use the 1/4" adapter with the Momentum headphones everything is tinny, quiet and crackles/spikes intermittently. I'm not just talking about a steady stream of poor audio quality - I mean a very unstable connection.

As I said, without the 1/4" adapter (into an iPhone) everything is dandy. I've tested the 1/4" adapter on other headphones with no problems. For instance, I tried a pair of Sennheiser HD25's with the same 1/4" adapter which sounds fine.

Is it possible that the extra functionality on the Momentum (a volume control which I presume sends commands down the wire to mp3 devices) is the bad apple? For example, as per [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_connector_%28audio%29#Mobile_phones) article on Wikipedia, it suggests that compatibility between 3.5mm connectors is not as straight forward as I originally thought.

Any insight on this would be great.

Comment: Are you using the 1/4" adapter that came with the cans?

Comment: An adapter didn't come with the cans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm that my suspicions about the TRRS (4 conductor) 3.5mm jack are correct. I went back to the Sennheiser Momentum box and found a different connecting cable within, a TRRS to TRS (without the added volume functionality). When pairing this with the 1/4" adapter, everything worked as expected.

For anyone stitching a cheap home studio together, make sure your cans haven't been optimised for  mp3 players. A quick/easy way to tell is to inspect the 3.5mm head. Note the difference between TRS and TRRS in this image pulled from Wikipedia:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to plug them in only up to the second/middle barrel of the ring.

Comment: While this is a helpful piece of information, it could be made in to a better answer if you also explain why this makes a difference in fixing the problem.  Right now it feels a bit like a comment that just barely squeaks in to being an answer.  Also, Welcome!

Comment: I agree with @AJHenderson - this would have been great as  a comment, but it feels a bit limp as an answer. Maybe add it as a comment to the accepted answer?

Comment: noob to the whole answering questions thing. Thanks for the advice guys.

Comment: half the explanation -> http://i.imgur.com/dFQyxMh.jpg - which may also be useful to guys historically ignoring the TRRS design